# DialogBox depth (z-index) in GWT

Tags: java, css, gwt, z-index, dialog

Having many GWT DialogBox'es, the first one always stays at the bottom and new ones are created on top.
What I am trying to obtain is a way to bring one of such dialogs on top when it is clicked.
I haven't found the GWT approach to handle depth (something related to a CSS label `z-index` but it lacks some documentation).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think, you can use something like this:

```
DialogBox d=new DialogBox();
d.getElement().getStyle().setZIndex(intValue);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also define a CSS rule for all `DialogBoxes` in the system:

```
@external gwt-PopupPanel;
@external gwt-DialogBox;
@external gwt-PopupPanelGlass;
.gwt-PopupPanel, .gwt-DialogBox, .gwt-PopupPanelGlass {
    z-index: 1000; 
}
```

(Remove the @external references if you are not using `CssResource`).

That way all your popups, dialogboxes and popup glasses will be over other items in the page. Make sure no other item has z-index above the value you choose (in my example, 1000).

Comment: Very elegant solution!